# Cannot decide a proper namespace for 'Character'

Tags: namespaces, naming-conventions

I am building a game engine, and I am actually having a very difficult time placing what kind of namespace to put `Character` under. This may be the single dumbest question I've ever posted on StackOverflow, but it's driving me nuts.

What would you guys do?

I don't really have any other namespaces yet defined. Characters have Sheets (Layout), which reference Traits (Statistics), etc. Everything is just kind of dumped into the root namespace right now.

Comment: There is hardly enough information for anyone to be able to come up with a good answer. What namespaces do you already have? What other classes? How are they structured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with Characters.

It's simple and to the point. You'll end up including lots of classes in it that describe player and non player characters, attributes, abilities, and so on, but they all refer to characters. Your base class for characters will likely be something like Character, so the naming collision is avoided.

And the guideline to avoid plurality in namespaces is just a guideline. There are cases where deviation is warranted (I'm looking at *you*, System.Windows.Forms).

Comment: Eh. Works for me. You know, one of the hardest parts of programming is just ...naming things.